# Problema con Logout en Middleware Guest Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {

     Route::auth();

});
```

Al hacer click en logout, me vuelve a redirigir al /home (como loguead). En cambio si el Route::auth(); lo saco del middleware, ahí funciona perfecto y cierra sesión.

Es raro por que en el LoginController tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
 }
```

y esto tendría que andar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `Route::auth();` efectivamente tiene que estar fuera del middleware, ya que el mismo se encarga de hacer toda la gestión de las rutas cuando se inicia y se cierra session, ese middleware te funcionará para las rutas que tengas configuradas para usar guest o no.